# Change brightness according to surrounding light in Android

Tags: android, screen-brightness

I want to change brightness of screen according to light.

I found links for getting brightness level and setting up brightness:

[Change screen brightness onPause (Android app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212835/change-screen-brightness-onpause-android-app)

[How to toggle auto brightness on and off? (not a repeat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339430/how-to-toggle-auto-brightness-on-and-off-not-a-repeat)

[changing screen brightness programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737579/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-in-android)

[Changing screen brightness programmatically (as with the power widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-as-with-the-power-widget)

But I want to change brightness **as per surrounding light**.
In short, I want to do same as auto brightness works.

How can I detect surrounding light? Can I trigger auto brightness functionality?

brightness is having value range between 0 to 255. I want to set brightness level according to surrounding light level which can not be 0 to 255. How can I get ratio between this two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Light Sensor Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433889/getting-light-sensor-value)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you are talking about question, is about getting level of surrounding light. How can I recognize or calculate brightness level according to  surrounding light.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you've already found answers to "how do I change the screen brightness?", and I've given you a link to "how do I detect the surrounding light?"; what else do you need?

Comment: A full example shows how to change brightness by coding, foreground, background. https://github.com/XinyueZ/brightnessdemo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution from myself:

I implemented shaking listener from [here](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2010/10/28/android-yahtzee-application-with-shake-detection).
I used aboce links also to make it completed.

I created **ShakeBrightService.java**

```
public class ShakeBrightService extends Service {

private ShakeDetector shakeBrightDetector = new ShakeDetector();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    shakeBrightDetector.stop();
    shakeBrightDetector.start(this, shakeBrightEventListener);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private ShakeEventListener shakeBrightEventListener = new ShakeEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShake() {
        setAutoBrightness(true);
    }
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void setAutoBrightness(boolean value) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AutoBrightness : " + value,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (value) {

        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
    } else {

        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity1.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);   
}

}
```

**Fake for refreshing view**
MainActivity1.java

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

    refreshBrightness(getBrightnessLevel());

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            finish();
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

private void refreshBrightness(float brightness) {

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (brightness < 0) {
        lp.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE;
    } else {
        lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
    }
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
}

int getBrightnessLevel() {
    try {
        int value = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        // convert brightness level to range 0..1
        value = value / 255;
        return value;
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

FakeActivity is having theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`, so silently brightness is changed.