# Brightness always returns 255 when auto brightness is on in Android

Tags: android, brightness, screen-brightness

I am getting 255 brightness when auto brightness is on in my phone (HTC Desire HD (2.3.3)).

My code

```
int value = Settings.System.getInt(c.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
```

How can I get brightness level when auto brightness is on?

### Tried

I tried, before getting brightness, I am setting `manual` mode. but getting 0 brightness when I set mode to `manual`.

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
```

How can I get brightness level when I phone is having auto brightness is `on`?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass different key in case of auto-brightness

```
float brightness = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                    "screen_auto_brightness_adj");
```

it should return value from -1 to +1

Comment: there is no such setting in android 5 (lollipop), so it throws an exception. It is as well not listed as a constant in `Settings.System`. Are you sure it works(worked)?

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams oLayOutParam = use from an activity getWindow().getAttributes();
```

`oLayOutParam.screenBrightness` is the value of brightness.

Comment: I can do this when my activity is running. actually I implemented service for which you can change brightness from anywhere by shaking. I can not get window from service. `WindowManager.LayoutParams oLayOutParam = getWindow().getAttributes();` will return in float. that is limited for activity itself.once activity is finished, it will be roll-backed.

Comment: You can always start an activity from service and then finish it as soon as you read brightness , you can set the brightness also using above API.

Comment: similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032588/cant-apply-system-screen-brightness-programmatically-in-android you need to have transparent activity.

Comment: I already tried with this.. see my implemetation but does not change brightness when fakeactivity finished..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101669/change-brightness-according-to-surrounding-light-in-android/14111181#14111181

Comment: so don't finish that activity  tell android to retain it using flags  , you can try something like alwaysRetainTaskState. Also you can put some Timer Task  to keep activity seem busy.

Comment: Thanks let me try.. My implementation works but I am not getting full brightness when auto brightness is on only.

Comment: What the F***?.. it's having context problem. I just changed `getApplicationContext()` to `getBaseContext()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854265/getapplicationcontext-getbasecontext-getapplication-getparent